# How to get Dapper to ignore/remove underscores in field names when mapping?

Tags: postgresql, mapping, dapper

There are many ways to map database field names to class names, but what is the simplest way to just remove the underscores?

```
    public IEnumerable<PersonResult> GetPerson(int personId)
    {
        using (var dbConnection = _dbConnectionFactory.Create(ConnectionStrings.ProjectXYZ))
        {
            IEnumerable<PersonResult> result =
                dbConnection.Query<PersonResult>("fn_get_person", new { personId },
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Table and database fields:

```
person
-------- 
person_id
full_name
```

Class that works: (dapper already ignores capitalization)

```
public class PersonResult
{    
    public int Person_Id { get; set; }
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to change the class to:

```
public class PersonResult
{    
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using PostgreSQL and not SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. :) Guessing you're asking because command type is "stored procedure" and postgresql just has functions? It still works.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```

job done ;p

Comment: Wow. I put this in my connection factory and it works, but is there a better place?

Comment: @scw well, you could write your own type map implementation... but: this works

Comment: Is there a way to do this conditionally for a single Dapper call?

Comment: Additionally, this doesn't seem to work with constructor arguments. Was it intentional? Seems unintuitive/inconsistent to me that it would try to match members without underscores when this flag was set, but would not do the same for ctor parameters. The flag name talks about `names` in general so one would expect that all name-matching logic would be affected.

Comment: @juleagon no, not intentional; I recommend logging a bug on github; edit: I  see you already have - thanks

Comment: This only seems to work one way -- when selecting underscored columns from the DB into non-underscored model properties. But there is no way to insert/update those same underscored DB columns from the same non-underscored model properties. :(

Comment: Worked perfect for me. What a time saver with hundred of tables using SNAKE_CASE. +1

Comment: For anyone looking at this thread then searching for the issue on GitHub about constructor parameters with underscores, here it is: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/818
However, as of right now there is still no solution. Altering the existing behaviour without adding a new config would break some known uses, including, apparently, Stack Overflow!

Comment: Where should `Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;` be placed within an application? `Program.cs`? A repository class?

Answer (score 4):

The [readme](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) doesn't show any support for renaming columns.  You could alias them in `select`:

```
select person_id as personid, full_name as fullname from fn_get_person();
```

as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904096/50552).

Comment: Actually, it is supported - see my answer